# No service worker in navigator on iOS Safari 11.3

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, service-worker

I'm trying register a service worker for my app on iOS Safari version 11.3 (that added service workers) but there is no service worker object present in the navigator. Here is what navigator looks like:

[image: Navigator]

I also tried running the app on OSX Safari 11.3 with the same results. What could I be missing here? If it is relevant I am using the default *create react app* service worker registration file, which doesn't do anything right now because there is no service worker in the navigator object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Service Worker can only work on `Https` and localhost sites. If navigator does not have `serviceWorker`, please check

Comment: Yes, it works on localhost and HTTPS but it has nothing to do with serviceWorker as an api not being available on the navigator object. 
I tried accessing it in ios Safari 12.4 and it's not there.